# Python code to average values during certain time periods in monthly data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello everyone I have a cvs file which contains a months worth of data in hourly intervals.  I need to get an average value of one of the columns for the time intervals of 12:00am-3:00am for the entire month.  I am using pandas.DataFrame to try and do this.

**Sample of data I am using**

```
    DateTime    current     voltage
11/1/2014 12:00 1.122061402 4.058617834
11/1/2014 1:00  1.120534925 4.060912132
11/1/2014 2:00  1.119349897 4.058656072
11/1/2014 3:00  1.118277733 4.060912132
11/1/2014 4:00  1.120365636 4.060912132
11/1/2014 5:00  1.120365636 4.060912132
```

i'd like to average column 2 from 12am-3am everyday for the entire month. I am thinking using a conditional statement on the time would be a good option however I am unsure of how to implement that conditional statement on date/time data.

Comment: `df['DateTime'].resample('3H').mean()`?

Comment: if I implement a 3H mean that will give me the mean for every 3 hours worth of data.  I'd like to get that mean for just the time periods of 12am-3am for the entire month.

Comment: Assuming the `DateTime` is the index would this work? `df.between_time('12:00', '3:00').resample('3H').mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you have already imported the file into a Pandas dataframe named `df`.

1. Confirm that your "DateTime" field is being recognized by pandas as a DateTime by checking the value of `df.dtypes`. If not, recast e.g. with:

   `df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])`
2. Double-check that times like 12 AM, 1 PM, etc. are being handled properly. (You have not indicated anything to distinguish 12 AM from 12 PM etc. in your dataset.) If not, you will need to devise an appropriate method to correct them or re-export them from the original source.
3. Create a DatetimeIndex from your DateTime field:

   `df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTime']))`
4. Now take Dmitry's suggestion (lightly modified):

   `>>> df.between_time('0:00', '3:00').resample('1D').mean()`

The index of the result will show the beginning of the time interval being averaged.

Edited to take into account new info in the comments.

Comment: thank you this works. Is there anyway to perform the df.between_time only on certain columns in the data?  Also can I save these values to a list?

Comment: Sure thing: try `list(df['current'].between_time('0:00', '3:00').resample('1D').mean())` to get only the mean current values in that timeframe, for example.